# Best way To load more data from API when scrolling to bottom as pagination

Tags: swift3

I want when scrolling to bottom in UITableView Fetch more date from API based on Page Number

Are use this method

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) > scrollView.contentSize.height ) && ! isLoadingList){
        self. isLoadingList = true
        self. loadMoreItemsForList()
    }
}
```

or used this method

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // fetch new data if user scroll to the last cell
    guard isLoadingIndexPath(indexPath) else { return }
    if self.totalItems > orders.count {
        fetchNextPage()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method to fetch more data while scrolling to bottom.